# Developer Mode check box is missing in Google Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Developer checkbox is missing in my Google Chrome Browser under extensions option..

I try to add a new extension in chrome browser but i am unable to do so because Developer mode is turned off. Check-box which unable developer mode in chrome is missing in my browser.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Chrome. Does it show if you press F12. Or are you talking about a plugin?

Comment: Thanks for taking this question Dave, I am using version 40.0 of Google chrome. No it's not showing anything like Press F12. 
I am not talking about plugin. 

My question is that check-box which turn on Developer Mode in Chrome extensions is missing in my browser.

Comment: Did you install chrome from official source

Comment: yes Dave i installed Chrome from official source.